# I am learning kotlin and I observed that when we access a property of a class in main function through dot operator it doesn't show any error

Tags: class, kotlin

```
class Car{
   val price=1000000
}

fun main(){
   val w =car()
   w.price
}
//This code runs and returns nothing
```

what's the use of **w.price** which does nothing and why the compiler doesn't show an error?

Comment: you are just accessing the *class property*, not doing anything with it. try `print(w.price)`. Read about Kotlin fields and properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In kotlin, you won't usually see the `getX` kind of functions as you usually write in Java. Instead, properties can have custom getters directly attached to them. For example, you could change your `price` property declaration to:

```
val price: Int get() {
    println("Got price!")
    return 1000000
}
```

So, by calling `w.price`, you are calling the Kotlin equivalent of `getPrice()` which is, by itself, a Java method in the background; as such, it may be indeed computing something (in this case, it prints "Got price!"), so it is a valid expression all by itself.